# How do I calculate the inductance for a step-down DC-DC converter?

Tags: power-electronics

I'm going through the datasheet of [this step down converter.](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/DC-DC-Converters_UMW-Youtai-Semiconductor-Co-Ltd-LM2596S-5-0_C347421.html)

The schematic diagram suggests that a 33µH power inductor should be used.

If I follow the formula:
Inductance (L) = (Vin - Vout) * (1 - D) / (ΔIL * Fs)

- Vin: 12V;
  -Vout: 5V;
- ΔIL: 0.3 * 3A = 0.9A;
- D (duty cycle) = 90%;
- Fs (switching frequency) = 150,000 Hz (150 kHz)

I get 47µH inductance:

L = (12V - 5V) * (1 - 0.9) / (0.3 * 150,000 Hz) ≈ 47.11 µH

Why do I get a different number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I follow the formula:

That formula applies to CCM (Continuous Conduction Mode) operation where the inductor current either never drops to zero or just kind of touches to zero and rises again in zero time (Critical Conduction Mode - CrCM). This also ensures that D is always equal to output voltage to input voltage ratio: D = Vout / Vin.

Also the inductor's ripple current, or simply \$ΔI_L\$ factor, doesn't have to be taken 30% of output current. That parameter can be anything between 0.0000...01 and 1.0 but the consequences will be different: The higher it is, the larger ripple current therefore larger output capacitance requirement. The lower it is, the higher (and possibly, physically bigger) inductance. 0.2 ~ 0.3 is a good compromise between these two.

Now, for your case, assuming a CCM operation, D will be \$D=5/12 = 0.417\$. If you select a \$ΔIL\$ of \$ΔI_L=0.3 \cdot 3A = 0.9A\$ then L will be

$$
L=\frac{(V_{in}-V_{out})}{ΔI_L \ } \ \frac{D}{F_s}\approx 22\mu H
$$

This is normally the minimum inductance. So the suggestion is fine.

Few things worth to note:

- The calculation of inductance is based on an assumption of CCM operation. The higher it is, the smaller ripple current and therefore the more "guaranteed" CCM operation.
- If you use the maximum possible input voltage instead of nominal value (12V, in your case), that'll give you an inductance value to, kind of, "guarantee" CCM operation across the entire input voltage range.

Comment: Hello Rohat, the ripple current in the inductance depends on \$V_{out}\$ and \$(1-D)T_{sw}\$ or \$V_{in}-V_{out}\$ and \$DT_{sw}\$. You may want to look at this [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/679905/calculating-inductor-value-for-my-buck-converter/679913#679913).

Comment: @VerbalKint I got your point but for the same input parameters (input & output voltages and switching frequency) and the same operation (CCM here), can't we say `higher L brings lower peak-to-peak ripple`? This was what I tried to say. I think what you meant was `once you select L the ripple becomes voltage- and frequency-dependent`. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I simply meant the formula to determine the inductor either uses \$V_{out}\$ and \$1-D\$ or \$V_{in}-V_{out}\$ and \$D\$. Your formula uses \$V_{in}-V_{out}\$ and \$1-D\$ whereas it should be \$D\$. This is what I gave in the answer I linked.

Comment: As a side comment, I looked at the DS posted by the OP and it is a Chinese brand, Youtai Semi that I never heard of. If you compare the illustrations in their [datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2305060948_UMW-Youtai-Semiconductor-Co---Ltd--LM2596S-5-0_C347421.pdf) with those in the original Nat-Semi part [LM2596](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf?ts=1698123710414&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) now TI, they are the same! They did not even bother making their own drawings, just shamelessly copying the original ones : |

Comment: @VerbalKint okay I got your point now. Thanks for the clarification. About your second comment, I've seen similar things several times. There was an NXP (then Phillips) IC that was about to become obsolete. We found a far-eastern manufacturer having the "same" part *(just the first 3 letters changed from TEA to something else)* with an exact copy of the original datasheet - only header and footer were different :@

Comment: @VerbalKint would you suggest to use TI? The price difference is significant - TI module is 5-6x more expensive.

Comment: I always suggest to use renowned brands: look at the characterization curves from Youtai Semi, they are supposed to be built by sampling production lots representative of a regular flow and then data are extracted on 30-40 parts. The curves are copied from the TI data-sheet! How can you trust these guys have truly extracted parameters? I don't know if this is for a hobby or professional usage, but very often, the few cents gained when buying parts are lost with a catastrophic failure, product recall etc. and the absence of technical support. So better select a solid and serious supplier : )